# Are .aspx helper files re-useable across web apps via nuget/dlls?

Tags: asp.net, dll, razor, template-engine, templating

Are .aspx helper files re-useable across web apps via nuget/dlls?  I have not attempted to compile .aspx (or any templating code) into a dll and then re-use them on another web app.  Is this even possible, or are there better ways of sharing html/aspx components?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at the [following article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/).

Comment: I suspect though that this isn't exactly a supported practice by Microsoft then?

Comment: @lucidquiet, why do you think so? Writing a custom virtual path provider for views embedded in separate assemblies is definitely something quite usual. Of course if your definition of Microsoft supported practice is something that is 2 clicks away and 3 lines of code, then you will be disappointed as this is not the case for embedding views in separate assemblies.